# Gradient of matrix function using the trace

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

For the function

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sparsecost}
\mathcal{C}\left(\mathbf{B}, \mathbf{A}\right) = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^K \left ( \sum_j \left[ {S}_{kj} - \sum_i {A}_{ki} \: {B}_{ij} \right]^2
  + \lambda \sum_i \log\left(1+\frac{{A}_{ki}^2}{\sigma^2}\right) \right),
\end{equation}

I need to find the partial derivative $\partial \mathcal{C}/\partial \mathbf{A}$ and have been told it's a scalar function of matrix A only.

It's also given that the trace function should be used and the first part of the equation can be written as $\text{Tr}(\mathbf{E}\mathbf{E}^\top) / K $,  where $\mathbf{E}$ is the error matrix $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{S}-\mathbf{AB}$ and $\text{Tr}(\mathbf{X}) = \sum_i {X}_{ii}$.

The following identities are given:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\, \text{Tr}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^\top)}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \frac{\partial\, \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}^\top)}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{A}
\qquad {\sf and} \qquad
\frac{\partial\, \text{Tr}(\mathbf{X} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^\top)}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^\top\right).
\end{equation}

I haven't managed to get anywhere on this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a partial derivative. It is a gradient.  Please edit. Use `\nabla`.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}
\def\C{\cal C}\def\p{\partial}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\cLR#1{\left(\c{#1}\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Use the symbols $\odot$ and $\oslash$ to denote the *Hadamard*
(aka elementwise) product and quotient, and a colon to denote the *Frobenius* product $-$ which is a very convenient and compact algebraic notation for the *trace* function.
$$\eqalign{
A:P &= P:A
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}P_{ij}
 \;=\; \trace{A^TP} \\
A:P &= I:A^TP \;=\; P^T:A^T \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
Note that Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
and that $J$ is the Hadamard identity.
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{P\odot L} &= \LR{A\odot P}:L
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}P_{ij}L_{ij} \\
J\odot A &= A\odot J = A\oslash J = A \\\\
}$$

---

For typing convenience, define the all-ones matrix $(J)$
and the following matrix variables.
$$\eqalign{
E &= AB-S &\qiq dE = dA\;B \\
P &= A\odot A + \s^2J &\qiq dP = 2A\odot dA \\
M &= J\oslash P \\
L &= \log(P) &\qiq dL=dP\oslash P = M\odot dP \\
}$$

Rewrite the cost function in matrix notation (i.e. without any explicit summations) using the above definitions. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\C
 &= \LR{\frac{E:E + \l\log\LR{P\oslash\s^2J}:J}{K}} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{E:E + \l J:L - 2\l\log(\s)\,J:J}{K}} \\
d\C
 &= \LR{\frac{2E:dE + \l J:dL}{K}} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{2E:\LR{dA\,B} + \l J:\LR{M\odot\c{dP}}}{K}} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{2\LR{EB^T}:dA + \l M:\cLR{2A\odot dA}}{K}} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{2{EB^T} + 2\l{A\oslash P}}{K}}:dA \\
\grad{\C}{A}
 &= \LR{\frac{2{\c{E}B^T} + 2\l{A\oslash\c{P}}}{K}} \\
 &= \frac 2K\BR{\cLR{AB-S}B^T+\l A\oslash\cLR{A\odot A+\s^2J}} \\\\
}$$
Since $P$ is independent of $B$,
the gradient wrt $B$ is much simpler to calculate.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\C}{B}
 &= \frac 2K\BR{A^T\c{E}} 
 \;=\; \frac 2K\BR{A^T\cLR{AB-S}} \\
}$$